# Genetic algorithm for specific assignment

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, compound-assignment, biological-neural-network

Assume I have a working place with many rooms. 
Every room needs employees of specific specialities. 
Every employee has his specialities.

I need to assign employees to work in the rooms for a week and I want it to be done in the most efficient way. 
Employees way have other restrictions such as vacations etc.

I was wondering if I would define a problem as assigning the employees to the rooms in the best most efficient way possible could be solved with a genetic algorithm?

If not what is the right approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for reviewing code. If you have a solution, but have some issues with he code, then we can help. However, this isn't the right place to ask about algorithms. You might want to try asking this in the machine learning or computer science sites instead. If you do, it would be helpful to mention what approaches you've considered, and why you think a genetic algorithm is the right approach.

Comment: The common approaches are constraint-programming, sat-solving and integer-programming, which are all complete methods. I would try those first.

Comment: This could be a simple instance of [Maximum Bipartite Matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) (or Maximum Weight Bipartite Matching), depending on the additional constraints.

Comment: @Ethan: this is simply wrong. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for reviewing code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for "the best most efficient way possible", the answer is no. 
Genetic algorithms may be used when the solution can be approximately correct.

It is hard to advise you on the right approach since your problem is not well described.